# ANTLR: lexing bash files, especially heredoc

Tags: antlr, antlr4, heredoc

I'm using *ANTLR* to lex bash files (for syntax coloring). Is it possible to lex rules with dynamic ends like [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
cat <<ENDTEXT
hello world, 
this text may contain 
any letters, even ' and "
ENDTEXT
```

or

```
cat <<FOO
here a different end-word
is used
FOO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only possible with a [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md).

Here's a quick example:

```
lexer grammar BashLexer;

@members {
  private boolean heredocEndAhead(String partialHeredoc) {
    if (this.getCharPositionInLine() != 0) {
      // If the lexer is not at the start of a line, no end-delimiter can be possible
      return false;
    }

    // Get the delimiter
    String firstLine = partialHeredoc.split("\r?\n|\r")[0];
    String delimiter = firstLine.replaceAll("^<<-?\\s*", "");

    for (int n = 1; n < delimiter.length(); n++) {
      if (this._input.LA(n) != delimiter.charAt(n - 1)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // If we get to this point, we know there is an end delimiter ahead in the char stream, make
    // sure it is followed by a white space (or the EOF). If we don't do this, then "FOOS" would also
    // be considered the end for the delimiter "FOO"
    int charAfterDelimiter = this._input.LA(delimiter.length() + 1);

    return charAfterDelimiter == EOF ||  Character.isWhitespace(charAfterDelimiter);
  }
}

HEREDOC
 : '<<' '-'? [ \t]* [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* NL ( {!heredocEndAhead(getText())}? . )* [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

ANY
 : .
 ;

fragment NL
 : '\r'? '\n'
 | '\r'
 ;
```

which would tokenize the input:

```
cat <<ENDTEXT
hello world, 
ENDTEXTS ENDTEXT
this text may contain 
any letters, even ' and "
ENDTEXT
```

like this:

```
ANY      `c`
ANY      `a`
ANY      `t`
ANY      ` `
HEREDOC  `<<ENDTEXT\nhello world, \nENDTEXTS ENDTEXT\nthis text may contain \nany letters, even ' and "\nENDTEXT`
EOF      `<EOF>`
```

Comment: I assume, it get's even more messy if the here doc start pattern is followed by some other redirection that needs to be parsed as separate element: `cat << ENDTEXT > file.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And don't forget optional quotes: `cat << 'ENDTEXT' > file.txt`